# Empty output files in Unix

Tags: file, unix, output, filenames

In Unix, I have run a software that creates files with that supposed to contains text and pictures. However, the first few output files look fine but the later files have the correct name but 0 bytes. Is there any possible explanation to this? Can it be attributed to the Unix directory running out of storage space?

Thanks

Comment: check with `df -h`

Comment: *Can it be attributed to the Unix directory running out of storage space?* Not if your code is actually checking the results of trying to write to the files.

Comment: How do I actually do that

Comment: Can there be any other explanation of the empty files other than not having enough space?

Comment: @erver if another parallel process opens for write, the file could be truncated. There are loads of reasons this is happening.  Please post some code.